# Analysing a shell script

Tags: parsing, scripting, shell

This would be part of a reverse-engineering project.

To determine and document what a shell script (ksh, bash, sh) does, it is comfortable, if you have information about what other programs/scripts it calls.

How could one automate this task? Do you know any program or framework that can parse a shell script? This way for instance, I could recognize external command calls -- a step to the right direction.

Comment: Nothing is as good as the human being.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Unfortunately the actual situation is a bit more worse.
I can't (at least not yet) _run_ these scripts. All I have is their source. That's why I'm thinking of parsing instead of some clever way of debugging/tracing.

Answer (score 1):

For bash/sh/ksh, I think you can easily modify their source to log what has been executed. That would be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

1. Get a list of distinct words in that script
2. Search $PATH to find a hit for each

?

Answer (score 0):

bash -v script.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

Bash's xtrace is your friend.

You can invoke it with:

- `set -x` at the top of your script,
- by calling your script with `bash -x` (or even `bash --debugger -x`),
- or recursively by doing `(set -x; export SHELLOPTS; your-script; )`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't actually run the script, try loading it into a text editor that supports syntax highlighting for Bash.  It will color-code all of the text and should help indicate what is a reserved word, variable, external command, etc.